# Using an overridden property in base class

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
class Info
{
    public string str;
};

class CarInfo : Info {}

class InfoContainer
{
    public virtual List<Info> info_list {get; set;}
    public bool is_known(Info inf)
    {
        if (-1 == info_list.FindIndex( i => i.str == inf.str) return false;
        return true;
    }  
}

class CarFleetInfo : InfoContainer
{
     new public List<CarInfo> info_list;
     CarFleetInfo()
     {
         info_list = new List<CarInfo>();
     }
}


Main()
{
    CarInfo c = new CarInfo();
    Info i = new Info();
    c.is_known(i);
}
```

I have few other "specific info" class that inherited from `Info` (like  `CarInfo` ), and few classes that inherited from `InfoContainer`, which are each overrides `info_list` with other a list of object of some "specific info".

now, the call to `c.is_known(i)` raise an exception saying `info_list` is null.

Comment: Your code is invalid to start with. You can't declare a virtual field.

Comment: you right. it's suppose to be a property.

Comment: And the one in the subclass? Note that even if you make that a property as well, it *isn't* overriding the base class one, because you're using `new` instead of `override`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `new` keyword on `new public List<CarInfo> info_list;`.  In this context, `new` means "Ignore the definition provided by my base class (if any), and use my own definition instead".  So when you set a `CarInfo`'s `info_list`, you're *not* setting the base `Info`'s `info_list`.  Then when you try to access the `info_list` that's part of an `Info`, it's null.

The best way to fix it is simply to take out the `CarInfo`'s `info_list` and simply use the base class's version.  This is the **correct** way to do what you're trying to do here, although there are others that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't overriding the `info_list` property, you are shadowing it.

To override the property you should use the `override` keyword instead of the `new` keyword, and then the code will work as intended.

When you shadow the property the subclass gets it's own property with the same name, that the base class doesn't know anything about.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) on a property which explicitly hides the member from its base class. It would be invalid to use `override` since a `List<Info>` is not a `List<CarInfo>`.

Instead consider using generics:

```
class Info
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

class CarInfo : Info {}

class InfoContainer<T>
    where T: Info
{
    public List<T> info_list { get; set; }

    public bool is_known(T inf)
    {
        if (-1 == info_list.FindIndex(i => i.Foo == inf.Foo)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}

class CarFleetInfo : InfoContainer<CarInfo>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You should be overriding instead of shadowing
2. You cannot override a method with a different signature

   class Info
       {
         public string str;
       };

   ```
   class CarInfo : Info {}

   class InfoContainer
   {
       public virtual List<Info> info_list {get; set;}
       public bool is_known(Info inf)
       {
         if (!info_list.Exists(p => p.str == inf.str)) return false;
         return true;
        }
   }

   class CarFleetInfo : InfoContainer
   {
        public override List<Info> info_list { get; set; }

        CarFleetInfo()
        {
           info_list = new List<Info>();
        }
   }
   ```

You cannot have public `List<CarInfo>` override public `List<Info>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't assign a `List<CarInfo>` to a `List<Info>`, so you can't override the `info_list` that way. To work around, you have to use generic class instead defined as follow:

```
class InfoContainer<T> where T : Info
{
  public virtual List<T> info_list {get; set;}
  public bool is_known(T inf)
  {
   if (-1 == info_list.FindIndex( i => i.str == inf.str) return false;
   return true;
  }
}
class CarFleetInfo<T> : InfoContainer<T> where T : CarInfo
{
  public override List<T> info_list {get;set;}
  public CarFleetInfo(){
    info_list = new List<T>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of a base class is to provide functions and definitions that will be overridden. Overriding a base class is meaningless. May be a good exercise on breaking a language, but in general you're creating a paradox and an infinite loop within your compiler. The override attribute means to the preprocessor that your code should run priority rather than it's base class operation.

However, you should still call the base class operation in most cases to ensure all fields and objects of the inherited object are instantiated and correctly initialized.

Comment: This isn't very clear, and I feel that it might be wrong, but it's unclear enough I can't tell.

Comment: Overriding a base class within itself is meaningless. It creates infinite recursion within the compiler. Generally you only override base class operations in the objects that inherit from the base class. Overriding a base class within itself creates infinite recursion, if it'll even compile.

This may or may not be the authors intention, but based on the title of this that's what it seems. Also, the purpose of the class depicted is not easily determined and I'm not able to understand what he's trying to do. So I'm only going off of the title of this thread.